# Write to file data from inputs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack-4

Need to write in txt file name, phone and film from inputs.
I'm new in Node, so I can't do this easy task, help me please

I tried to do it using fs module, but i cant use it in client side, so idk what to do with this problem. Project using webpack, node.js

Here's html form, from which i need to take data
    `html
    <form class="book-form">
        <input type="text" name='name' class="padding3" placeholder="Введіть ваше ім'я"/>
        <input type="text" name = 'phone_number'class="padding3" placeholder="Ваш номер телефону" />
        <select class = "select" name="select-films">

        </select>
        <input href ="" type="submit" class="button"> </input>
    </form>`

Comment: you cannot use the fs module in the browser, you have to make a XHR request to the node server to do that

Comment: post the data to the server, write a temporary file, and create a link to the file on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since `fs` is a node.js module, you cannot use it in your browser.

I suggest you make a express server, send a post request to it with the information and let the server write it to a database or local file.